# jsonschema: Unique Properties in an Object Array

Tags: json, unique, jsonschema

I have a schema with an array, and I would like to ensure that one property in the array is unique to all other of the same properties in the array. Using `uniqueItems` only ensures the entire object is unique, not one particular property.

An example will make this question more clear. In the arrays below, I want the `key` to be unique in the array, but `content` does not have to be. How would I make a json schema so that below `good_array` passes but `bad_array` fails?

```
good_array = [
  {"key":1, "content":"foo"},
  {"key":2, "content":"bar"},
  {"key":3, "content":"foo"}
]

bad_array = [
  {"key":1, "content":"foo"},
  {"key":1, "content":"bar"},
  {"key":3, "content":"foo"}
]
```

Comment: In Java, You can try create a Java wrapper class for jsonArray elements with equals method overriden and then try unique operation on Java collection.

Comment: As @relequestual says, this is not currently supported.  To that end, you may want to weigh in on this discussion: https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/538

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with JSON Schema. Sorry.

> Two JSON instances are said to be equal if and only if they are of
> the same type and have the same value according to the data model.
> Specifically, this means:
>
> ```
>   both are null; or
>
>   both are true; or
>
>   both are false; or
>
>   both are strings, and are the same codepoint-for-codepoint; or
>
>   both are numbers, and have the same mathematical value; or
>
>   both are arrays, and have an equal value item-for-item; or
>
>   both are objects, and each property in one has exactly one
>   property with a key equal to the other's, and that other property
>   has an equal value.
> ```

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-01#section-4.2.3

Comment: (You forgot to mention the open issue: https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/538)

Answer (score 1):

Since the JSON Schema standard does not support this I created a Python package (JsonVL) that supports unique constraints on values in objects in an array.

It can be installed with `pip install jsonvl`

And then run with:

```py
from jsonvl import validate

validate(data, schema)
```

Code examples in the GitHub repo: https://github.com/gregorybchris/jsonvl